# Non-linearity of neural network activation function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm relatively new to neural networks, though I have a reasonable background in mathematics and computing.

I understand that, because the composition of linear transformations is linear, a linear activation function can only give rise to a linear neural network.

Intuitively it seems likely that the deviation from linearity from the higher-order terms of the Taylor series of an activation function should compound somehow as we go deeper into the neural network.

Is there a theorem that looks at this?  For instance, what is the dependence of the (Taylor series of the) final result on the second-, third-derivative etc. of the activation function (eg of layer $\ell$)?

Could we approximate functions of arbitrary complexity using only quadratic activation functions? (beyond which, why is $\tanh$ seemingly so common and a function like
$$
g(z) = \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2 + 1}},
$$
which has very similar properties,
seemingly so rare?)

Comment: Have you encountered the so-called universal approximation theorems?

Comment: Only informally, really - I've just had a look at Wikipedia and it seems to help a little, but if you have any good references you'd recommend I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The classical references are Cybenko - Approximation by superpositions of a sigmoidal function (under whose terminology your proposed $g$ would be "discriminatory", but polynomials wouldn't, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216437/non-trivial-examples-of-non-discriminatory-functions); and Hornik, Stinchcombe, White - Multilayer feedforward networks are universal approximators. I am not familiar with any literature that discusses the relationship between universality and the Taylor development of your activation, sadly.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a proper read a bit later.  Is there an intuitive way of understanding why the definition you cite there is relevant?  The idea reminds me a bit of Sturm-Liouville theory and extracting coefficients through inner-products, but I can't see why anything resembling that would apply here.  Then again, my formal understanding of NN theory is patchy.

Comment: In a sense, it's a measure of non-linearity. A discriminatory function is one that is sufficiently non-linear that the only linear functional that kills all its translates must be the zero functional.

Comment: Could you expand a little on how it measures non-linearity?