# Does the term "polynomial" have a negative connotation over here?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials, approximation, neural-networks

I was looking at the statement of the "[Universal Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)":

> **Universal Approximation Theorem:** Fix a continuous function $\sigma:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ (activation function) and positive integers $d,D$. The function $\sigma$ is not a polynomial, if and only if, for every continuous function $f:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R^D$ (target function), every compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a continuous function $f_\epsilon:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^D$ (the layer output) with representation
> $$f_\epsilon =W_2\circ \sigma \circ W_1$$
> where $W_2,W_1$ are composable affine maps and $\sigma$ denotes component wise composition, such that the approximation bound
> $$\sup_{k\in K}\Vert f(x)-f_\epsilon (x)\Vert<\epsilon$$
> holds for all $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small (distance from $f$ to $f_\epsilon$ can be infinitely small).

For this theorem to work, i.e. for the function $f_\epsilon$ to approximate the function $f$ at some arbitrary level of precision - this theorem seems to specifically require that the function $\sigma$ to not be a polynomial. In a certain sense, it seems like being polynomial here has a negative connotation, in the sense that it might prevent the results of this theorem from being true.

Regarding this, I had the following questions:

1. Could this theorem have been written "Fix a continuous **non-polynomial** function $\sigma$ ..."?
2. Why can't the $\sigma$ function be polynomial?
3. What else could be the $\sigma$ function be (e.g. linear?)?
4. What happens if the $\sigma$ function is polynomial - does the Universal Approximation Theorem not hold?

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Also, see this: [Non-trivial examples of non-discriminatory functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216437/non-trivial-examples-of-non-discriminatory-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Have you even glanced at the references in the Wikipedia article? There is a paper in there called "Multilayer Feedforward Networks with a Non-Polynomial Activation Function Can Approximate Any Function" which answers all of your questions. Now, if the paper went a little over your head then that's fine, but your question reads very much like you haven't done any research beyond looking at the Wikipedia article. Please do that in the future.